# Which variable has to be with respect to for partial derivative in minimization algorithm?

Tags: calculus, algorithms, partial-derivative

The function has many variables. Which variable has to be with respect to for partial derivative in minimization algorithm? I would like to ask in general but probably, the example would be helpful.

For example from [this paper](http://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/okuno/Public/Interspeech2011-Hirasawa.pdf), they choose $x_j$ for doing $dQ'/dx_j$. Why we know it has to be with respect to $x_j$? The paper said...

"We can derive update rules by partial derivation on this function. First, we use a auxiliary function defined as

$$Q(X,\gamma)=- \sum_{j} \frac{1}{2\gamma}|x_{j}|^2+\frac{\gamma}{2}$$

where $γ_j$ is an auxiliary variable. This cost function satisfies
the three properties described in 3.1 (about $Q(θnew) ≤ Q+(θnew, φnew) ≤ Q+(θ, φnew) = Q(θ)$) and is equal to the original
cost function when
$$γ_j = |s_j|$$
When we solve $∂Q'/∂x_j = 0$, the update rule of separated signal $x_j$ is written as

$$x_j = 2\gamma" $$

Is it because $\gamma$ is just auxiliary variable so it is not important? If the function has more than one variables, which one will we choose for partial derivative?

Comment: Hard to tell without the full context, but I would guess that $j$ stands for an arbitrary index, and the statements such as $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x_j} =0$ are to hold for all $j$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I added some more information from paper. And yes, $j$ is like index of vector. Does it help?

Comment: It seems like you're not quoting directly from the paper, but instead substituting your versions of equations (8)–(12).

Answer (score 0):

Contextual clues indicate that the authors mean "**for each $j$ between $1$ and $J$**" whenever they refer to a symbol $s_j$ or $x_j$.

1. Notice how in some equations the index $j$ is summed over.  This makes it a dummy variable in those equations.  It would be confusing for $j$ to be a dummy variable in some equations and a fixed index in others.
2. At no point do the authors say "**for some** $j$", which would indicate a specific index.
3. The first-order conditions for a function of several variables $Q(x_1, \dots, x_J)$ to have a minimum are that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x_j} = 0$ **for each $j$**.

I am not sure why the authors use $\gamma_j$ in some places and $\gamma$ in others (e.g., the caption for Figure 3).  Could it be that $J=1$ in those cases, so there is only a single variable?

It seems to me that these ambiguities should have been caught by an editor.  You might get full clarity by emailing one of the authors.